# How do I get rrdtool from homebrew to work with ruby on macOS

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rrdtool

In our Rails application we do `require 'RRD'` at some point, but that results in a `cannot load such file -- RRD`. So obviously I used homebrew to `install rrdtool`, but the error remains.

The docs at https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/prog/rrdruby.en.html provide two options:

Either:

```rb
$: << '/path/to/rrdtool/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-linux'
require "RRD"
```

In my `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rrdtool/1.8.0/lib` directory there's no mention of ruby, which is because of the `--disable-ruby-site-install` flag in the formula, because when I skip that flag I do actually get something: `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/rrdtool/1.8.0/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin21`. However replacing the `path/to` string with this path still gives the error.

Or:

> If you use the --ruby-site-install configure option you can drop the $: line since the RRDtool module will be found automatically.

Which is a little confusing (and probably outdated) because here it seems that ruby site install is disabled by default and you have to enable it proactively, whereas in the formula it's actually actively disabled.

Either way: both options didn't do the trick for me and if there's a solution without homebrew that's also fine.

For good measure: I'm on macOS Monterey

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

For the most part, I'd say that using a non-standard gem without a Ruby version manager is your main issue. There are instructions on the rrdruby site for installing it, but they don't follow typical conventions, so your mileage will vary.

### Some Practical Suggestions

The `require` keyword is for gems, not binaries. You need to have an rrdtool-related gem installed, available to your Ruby instance (usually through a Bundler Gemfile or gemspec, or via the *RUBYOPTS* environment variable or your in-process Ruby *$LOAD_PATH*), and then require the correct name of the gem in your code. For example, using the older rrd-ffi gem:

```sh
# use sudo if you're installing it to the system,
# but I would strongly recommend a ruby version
# manager instead
gem install rrd-ffi
```

```rb
# in your Ruby class/module file
require "rrd"
```

For the [gem you seem to be using](https://github.com/oetiker/rrdtool-1.x), you have to compile the gem first to make it usable, and then ensure it's available in your Ruby *$LOAD_PATH* (or other gem lookup mechanism) before trying to require it. The error message you're seeing is basically telling you that a gem with that name is not available as called within any of the standard lookup locations.

Again, I'd suggest reading the build documentation for your gem, and then seeing if you can install it as part of a Bundler bundle, RVM gemset, or other non-system approach if you can. Otherwise, follow the directions for the [rrdruby](https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/prog/rrdruby.en.html) tool, which is *not* available as a standard Rubygems.org gem, in order to make it available before trying to require it.

### Beware of Outdated or Non-Standard Gems

Most of the RRD gems I found were quite old; most were 7-8 years old or older, so their compatibility with current Rubies is potentially suspect. The gem-builder you're using is newer, but doesn't seem to be designed as a standard gem, so you need to build it and install it in a suitable lookup path before it can be required. Installing gems as system gems is almost always a bad idea, so I'd *strongly* recommend building it from source and using a ruby version manager rather than following the rrdtool author's atypical suggestions. YMMV.